# CQ5.5 Updating an existing package through CURL

Tags: aem, crx

I am using a series of CURL request to create my package.

**What I am doing currently**: I created a new package, added filters to it and then built the package.

**Create package:**

`curl -f -N -u ${USER}:${PASS} -d "packageName=${PACKAGE}&groupName=${GROUP}" "${CMS_HOST}/crx/packmgr/service/exec.json?cmd=create"`

**Apply Filters:**

`curl -f -N -u ${USER}:${PASS} -F "path=/etc/packages/${GROUP}/${PACKAGE}.zip" -F "packageName=${PACKAGE}" -F "groupName=${GROUP}" -F "version=" -F "description=" -F "thumbnail=" -F "filter=${FILTER}" -F "_charset_=UTF-8" "${CMS_HOST}/crx/packmgr/update.jsp"`

**Build Package:**

`curl -f -N -u ${USER}:${PASS} -d "cmd=build" "${CMS_HOST}/crx/packmgr/service/script.html/etc/packages/${GROUP}/$PACKAGE.zip"`

**What I want to do**: *Add more filters* **to this package** and build it again.

I am wondering if there is a way to update an existing package. I have been searching around to see how we can do this but have failed. Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Update: Added the CURL commands I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with an example where i have a package with two filters already
[image: Package with filters]

Going to add another filter

**CURL for Create a Filter Node**

```
curl --data jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured --user admin:admin http://localhost:4502/etc/packages/my_packages/testcurl.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/filter/f2
```

**Add the Filter properties**

```
curl -u admin:admin -Froot="/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/toolbar" http://localhost:4502/etc/packages/my_packages/testcurl.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/filter/f2.rw.html
```

IF required add additional properties (i.e. "**mode**" & "**rules**") for the Default package behaviour

```
curl -u admin:admin -Fmode="replace" http://localhost:4502/etc/packages/my_packages/testcurl.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/filter/f2.rw.html

curl -u admin:admin -Frules@TypeHint="String[]" -Frules=" " -Frules=" "http://localhost:4502/etc/packages/my_packages/testcurl.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/filter/f2.rw.html
```

Finally build your package to affect additional filter to add to your existing package

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json/etc/packages/my_packages/testcurl.zip?cmd=build
```

[image: Final updated package]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This helped a lot :)

Comment: Now, I am writing a script in Ruby and converting the CURL commands to POST requests. I could get everything working except for curl -u admin:admin -Frules@TypeHint="String[]" -Frules=" " -Frules=" "http://localhost:4502/etc/packages/my_packages/testcurl.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/filter/f2.rw.html. I am not able to pass the "rules" array. Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

All the packages are stored under `/etc/packages/my_packages` path which can be modified by standard curl commands for node management. All packages have filters as sub-nodes.

All package manager commands are available via `/crx/packmgr/service.jsp?cmd=help`

For example, in order to build a package use `/crx/packmgr/service.jsp?cmd=build`

Comment: Yes. I have been there. I have updated my question with the CURL commands I am using. Once I have built the package, if I want to add more filters to the SAME package how can I do it? Currently, if I run the above mentioned 'Apply filter' command, it overwrites the existing filters. It looks like it is in some kind of overwrite mode instead of update/append mode.

Comment: You can use curl data post like `curl --data "jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured&mode=replace" --user <user>:<password> <aem-server>/etc/packages/my_packages/<package>.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/filter/**f0**` where **f0** is the path of new filter you want to add. All new filters are added as f**N** where **N** is incremental